# JQuery Ajax settings : Timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, timeout

I'm using the JQuery ajax method to call a service with rest api. I have added a timeout value of 5 seconds to my service call.

```
$.ajax({
    timeout:5000,
    type:"POST",
    url:"serviceurl",
    data: fooandstuff,
    error:function(){},
    success:function(data){ console.log(data); }
   });
```

This is my function call. I was testing this when my service was down and I don't think it actually timed out after 5 seconds. Because it took a while and then when service was up it actually returned the response.

So, I'm trying to understand how jquery actually implements this timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `error` callback function try to debug if you are getting `timeout` like this-

```
error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
```

*error event handler takes the three arguments (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, and message) when a timeout happens, the status arg will be 'timeout'*

A working Timeout Demo :

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PsjJV/)